# How exactly does the 'hex' prefix work for bytes?

Tags: solidity, bytes

I found some code snippets using the 'hex' prefix before a string in a bytes variable.  I can't seem to find its description in the solidity docs.

```
bytes memory bytesVar = "0x01";
bytes memory bytesVarWithHex = hex"01";
```

When I log the results they return 0x30783031 and 0x01, respectively.  What exactly is it doing for the variables being stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bytes memory bytesVar = "0x01";` is converting the literal string "0x01" to UTF-8 and storing that, and `bytes memory bytesVarWithHex = hex"01";` is storing the hex number 1